# View never loads

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {

    MainView *Main=[[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    // This module to collect metrics for Notification received, Notification displayed
    UINavigationController *NavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Main];

    // react to shortcut item selections
    NSLog(@"A shortcut item was pressed. It was %@.", shortcutItem.localizedTitle);
    if([(NSString *)shortcutItem.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"Store"])
    {
        PurchaseView *purchaseViewController = [[PurchaseView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PurchaseView" bundle:nil];
        [NavBar pushViewController:purchaseViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I enter the **if([(NSString *)shortcutItem.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"Store"])** loop and I see the code executing. But the PurchaseView.xib never loads. I have similar code for Push Notification and it works when I am pushing a view to load.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW - standard naming conventions state that variable and method names should start with lowercase letters. Only classnames should begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: You are creating `NavBar` but don't seem to be making it part of the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: You setup your navigation controller but your never display the navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I forgot to add     [self.window setRootViewController:NavBar];

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is bad view hierarchy. You added your `XIB` file's view controller to a brand new `UINavigationController` which does not exists anywhere in the view hierarchy. I believe you want to do something like this:

```
UINavigationController *navBar = (UINavigationController *) self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
[navBar pushViewController:purchaseViewController animated:YES];
```

Again, above is a hypothetical example. You need to find out the right `UINavigationController` in your view hierarchy.